# View the SQL commands from makemigrations

Tags: mysql, django

I am getting an error when I try to `migrate`. I have added lots of unique contraints and I'm not sure which one I haven't migrated yet.

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '16-' for key 'mainapp_caption_photo_id_1e4a8c0d_uniq'")
```

How do I view what is being ran in `migrate` so I can inspect the IntegrityError myself and fix the duplicate entries? I want to see what unique key is trying to be placed.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the command you want is [sqlmigrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-sqlmigrate):

```
python manage.py sqlmigrate myapp 0001 # migration number
```

This will show you what SQL command is being run.

Answer (score 0):

You could run

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE <TABLENAME>
```

and locate the key entry 'mainapp_caption_photo_id_1e4a8c0d_uniq' to identify the columns for the unique key.